# Qt, QTransform rotation

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, drawing, qpainter

I'm trying to draw text "on cylinder". It means, that I have five rows of text. Top row is rotated by the X axis for 10 degrees. The second for 5 degrees. The middle is not rotated at all. The four's row is rotated for -5 degrees. The five's is rotated for -10 degrees.
Rows 1, 2, 3 draws OK, but something is wrong with 4,5 rows. What am I doing wrong ?
I provides an image for understanding a problem and code snippet:

```
for( int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; ++i )
{
    const QRect r( x2, y2, textWidth, itemHeight );

    const QString text = sections.at( section ).values.at( index );

    int rsc = 0;


    p->save();

    rsc = widgetHeight / 2 - y;

    p->setTransform(QTransform().rotate(rsc, Qt::XAxis));


    if( type == Section::DaySectionShort ||
        type == Section::DaySectionLong )
    {


        QStringList values = text.split( QLatin1Char( ' ' ) );

        p->setPen(
            lighterColor( opt.palette.color( QPalette::WindowText ), 75 ) );
        p->drawText( r, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextSingleLine, values.at( 0 ) );

        p->setPen( opt.palette.color( QPalette::WindowText ) );
        p->drawText( r, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextSingleLine, values.at( 1 ) );
    }
    else
    {
       p->drawText( r, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextSingleLine, text );
    }

    p->setTransform(QTransform().rotate(-rsc, Qt::XAxis));

    index = nextIndex( index, sections.at( section ).values.size() );
    y += itemHeight + itemTopMargin;

    p->restore();
}
```

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVp6S.png)

Comment: Why do you set `QTransform().rotate(-rsc...` and don't use the `p`? And why `rsc` is calculated so strange?

Comment: Because in the beginning I need to rotate, for example, for 10 degrees. After that I need to rotate another string for -10 degrees, thats why I am using rsc and -rsc.

Comment: But you draw nothing between this set and next loop iteration. Don't you do it in the `nextIndex` function?

Comment: lines of code with p->drawText draw text.
Look at link to the image added by my bottom to the code snipet. This is an image, drawn by this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided a minimal *complete* code that reproduces the problem, I cannot guess what is wrong there. But the most probable reason is incorrect `rsc` calculation. At least the following draft works:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        QFont f = font();
        f.setPointSize(15);
        setFont(f);
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
        QWidget::paintEvent(event);
        QPainter p(this);

        const int itemHeight = fontMetrics().height();
        const int itemTopMargin = 15;
        const int xOffset = 15;
        int y = itemHeight;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            // The angle is in range [-40, 40]. Remove " * 4" for [-10, 10].
            const int rsc = (10 - 5 * i) * 4;
            qDebug() << i << ":\t" << rsc << "\t" << y;

            /*
                Rotation must be performed relative to central point of the
                drawn item. Transformations below are applied in reverse order.
                At first translate item to make it's center in (0, 0). At
                second rotate it relative to X axis. At third move the item to
                desired position.
            */
            QTransform transform;
            transform.translate(xOffset, y + itemHeight / 2);
            transform.rotate(rsc, Qt::XAxis);
            transform.translate(0, - itemHeight / 2);
            p.setTransform(transform);

            p.drawText(QPoint(), QString("(Item no. %1)").arg(i + 1));

            y += itemHeight + itemTopMargin;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyWidget widget;
    widget.setMaximumSize(200, 250);
    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The transformation used here is complicated because of need to rotate each item relative to it's central `y`, not `y = 0`. This also may be the case.

Font and angles are increased to see considered effects better.