# Qt. Rotation objects

Tags: qt, text, rotation, drawing

I want to rotate a text about X axis. First to 10 degrees, then to -10 degrees.
How should I do it ?
Just like:

```
painter->setTransformation(QTransform().rotate(10));
painter->drawText(x1, y1, w, h, text);
painter->setTransformation(QTransform().rotate(-10));
painter->drawText(x2, y2, w, h, text);
```

Looks like this code works wrong? Can anyone help ?

Comment: With all due respect, "Looks like this code works wrong" doesn't really give us much to go on.  `QTransform::rotate` will rotate about the z axis by default.  Have you tried `QTransform().rotate(10, Qt::XAxis)?

Comment: Thanks fro your reply! Yes, I tried. But I have an isssue. It is described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338784/qt-qtransform-rotation